# Markdown parse/preview bug

Tags: bug, markdown, editor, markdown-rendering

I have a old bug in this old question, it appeared then I created the question:

[HTML file input control with capture and accept attributes works wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong)

You can open it and find the `#` symbol in the middle. If I delete this symbol, the table after it will not parse/preview correctly:

http://screencast.com/t/m3ioSYVD5

Then I created a question, I thought that this parser/preview behavior is temporary, but it still for now.